# C#. Как переназначить кнопку закрытия программы(крестик в углу)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста как переназначить кнопку закрытия программы(крестик в углу)?
Хочу повесить на нее другое действие.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Перехватывай событие на нажатие кнопки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

> `FormClosing` Событие возникает при закрытии формы. Если форма
>   закрывается, она удаляется, освобождение всех ресурсов, связанных с
>   формой. При отмене этого события форма остается открытой. Чтобы
>   отменить закрытие формы, задайте `Cancel` Свойства `FormClosingEventArgs`
>   передается обработчику событий для `true`.
>
> Если форма отображается как модальное диалоговое окно, нажав кнопку
>   Закрыть (кнопка со знаком `X` в правом верхнем углу формы) приводит к
>   скрытию формы и `DialogResult` Задайте свойства `DialogResult.Cancel`.
>   Можно переопределить значение, назначенное `DialogResult` Свойства,
>   когда пользователь щелкает Закрыть кнопку, задав `DialogResult` свойство
>   в обработчике событий для `FormClosing` события формы.

Comment: Спасибо! FormClosing отлично выполняет. Вопрос на засыпку) А если надо чтобы функции ALT+F4 остались?

Comment: @technor, предположу, что так: объявляем глобальную переменную qqw = true, ловим событие нажатие сочетания клавиш alt+f4, меняем qqw = false, вызываем событие Form.FormClosing, в обработчике которого пишем: e.Cancel = qqw

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Работает!

Comment: @technor, пометка ответа зелёной галочкой - немного приблизит меня к возможности оставлять комментарии под чужими сообщениями. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers раздел "Отметьте ответ как решение"

Comment: @technor, как вариант - самому написать ответ с примером рабочего кода и отметить его как решение. думаю в данном случае это будет уместно. также можно упомянуть устаревший метод `Form.Closing`